# XPath/XML parsing to wrap groups of elements

Tags: xml, xpath

This is probably pretty straight forward, but I'm missing something... I have an XElement, within which I need to find groups of a particular element and insert a new parent element for the group.

ie, in the example below, I need to create a new element and add it to the tree as the parent of the group of z elements -

```
<x>
    <z />
    <z />
    <z />
</x>
```

becomes:

```
<x>
    <y>
        <z />
        <z />
        <z />
    </y>
</x>
```

There won't be anything other elements between the Z elements, but there may be multiple instances of consecutive elements in the xml.

I'd prefer to avoid using XSLT to manipulate the data, if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. What do you mean in XPath? You can use XPath to check for groups, but still you'd need DOM/XSLT/other to modify and generate an output document. 2. what exactly do you mean by "group" (one element, more elements, can there be other elements in between the <z/> ones? )

Comment: Sorry - half my question dropped out. Will edit my original post

Answer (score 1):

XPath can only access an existing document, it can't create a new one.

Technologies you can use to create a new document include XSLT, XQuery, Linq, etc.

It's difficult to answer the question without knowing WHY you don't want to use XSLT, which for many of us would be the obvious and simplest way to do it.

Comment: Just a personal preference really - I'd prefer to use Linq or XQuery. Given that I'm constrained to xsl 1.0, from what I've seen it gets pretty verbose

Comment: Well, when you are copying most of the data unchanged, the XSLT solution us usually more concise than the XQuery solution. It's true that the XSLT 2.0 solution will often be half the length of the 1.0 one, however. I'm surprised that Linq is available on a platform where XSLT 2.0 isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to use something (DOM/XSLT/etc) to modify the document or output a new one.

Having said that, you can approach the problem by targetting first `<z/>` element of a group (thus going through groups) and then wrapping it and the other elements inside the group.

1. `//z[not(preceding-sibling::z)]` will give you all `<z/>` elements which have no preceding-sibling(s) `<z/>`, so you have first in group (and number of elements returned is number of groups).
2. Wrap that element using DOM/other in your `<y>` element.
3. Wrap the other elements in the group. On the first `<z/>` element use `following-sibling::z` to get elements 2 through N of group.